# How to get the html index (counting in units of each html code string character) of a node?

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, nodes

#### question

How to get the html index (counting in units of each html code string character) of a node?

#### ex

you have an html code

```html
<div id="main_parag">Sample 789<!-- comment 23 -->29<script>let i = 47;</script>59<strong>69<span id="AA">Get_My_Index</span></strong></div>
```

how to get the html index of `#AA` relative to (starting from) `#main_parag`?

```js
  document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="main_parag">Sample 789<!-- comment 23 -->29<script>let i = 47;</script>59<strong>69<span id="AA">Get_My_Index</span></strong></div>';
  let elt_outer = $('#main_parag')[0];
  let elt_inner = $('#AA')[0];
  let indHtml = get_IndHtml_of_eltInner_in_eltOuter(elt_inner, elt_outer); // expect 71
  
  // Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element) 
  // ^ this is not what I wanted, I want html index, not node index; 
  // plus that `AA` is not a direct child, but nested
```

#### comments

- (the element id may not be available in some cases)
- (I dont think Regex find is safe -- when there are multiple same strings?)

Comment: Why not parse the HTML and directly access the `<span id="AA">` element?

Comment: @SebastianSimon My point was not to get the element, I want to get the index. It can be used for, eg: comparing the node position inside a document.

Answer (score 1):

Walk over every element with a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) object, start counting, and stop whenever you find your element.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#main_parag');
const target = document.querySelector('#AA');

function getIndexOfElement(root, target) {
  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    root,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
  );

  let index = 0;
  let currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;

  while (currentNode && currentNode !== target) {
    currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
    index++;
  }

  return index;
}

const index = getIndexOfElement(root, target);
console.log(index);
```

```html
<div id="main_parag">Sample 789
  <!-- comment 23 -->29
  <script>
    let i = 47;
  </script>

  59<strong>69<span id="AA">Get_My_Index</span></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: I know `TreeWalk` may be helpful for nested case, but as I said above, `I want html index, not node index`.

Comment: What does the HTML index mean? That is not a term I've heard anybody use before.

Comment: -`html index` stands for: the index of a character inside the html code -- thats what I mean by `(counting the html code string)`; 
- I gave an example above, with the expected index, you may understand what I mean from that.  - I dont know if such term every exist, so I named it in that way.

Comment: Okay, so just the position of `#AA` within the string? Would using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) on your string help you get that result?

Comment: @EmielZuubrier 
- Because a Regex find fails to work if there are multiple same strings (as I mentioned in the post). 
- (I can kinda fix that (if they just repeat as Node.ELEMENT_NODE), but that is complicated when "html Node.COMMENT_NODE" are involved).

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't require a Regex. It looks for the first occurence and returns the index of that. What would be the preferred outcome with multiple or no occurences anyway?

Comment: I dont understand why that not matters. If just using Regex find (or non regex, doesnt matter), say 2 elements `AA`,`BB` with same `outerHtml` in 2 different position, you want to find the index of `BB`, but it returns index of `AA` . Its just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So you could use just a more suitable selector, e.g.

```
const span = document.querySelector('#main_parag>strong>span[id="AA"]');
```

The above is just theoretical - I do have no environment to test it.
But I created it using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: The structure provided above is just an example, it can be different in other cases. As I said above `the element id may not be available in some cases`

Comment: Then build a selector avoiding the id attribute, such as `#main_parag>strong>span`. This assumes then that the span element is the only one in that hierarchy.

Comment: The point is not about how to pick the element with a selector, the point is about the index of that element...

Answer (score 0):

#### solution

- @logic:: add a node as an unique indicator before the node you want to search on, then just use regex to find (remember to remove that node once done)
- @code::

  ```js
      class RegexUtil {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex
        /**
         * @param {String} literal_string
         * @returns {String}
         */
        static escapeRegex(literal_string) {
          return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
        }

        /**
         * @param {String} string
         * @returns {String}
         */
        static escapeRegexReplacement(string) {
          return string.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
        }
      }

      /**
       * @param {Node} node_inner 
       * @param {Element} elt_outer 
       * @returns {Number} return -1 means no match -- node_inner is not inside elt_outer
       */
      function get_IndHtml_of_nodeInner_in_eltOuter(node_inner, elt_outer) {
        if (node_inner === undefined || elt_outer === undefined) {
          throw new ReferenceError();
        }
        if (!(elt_outer.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)) {
          throw new TypeError();
        }

        const content_SearchOn = elt_outer.innerHTML;

        // decide the delimRegexBf
        let html_delimRegexBf;
        let time_now;
        let delimRegexBf_tagName = 'delim-regexbf';
        /** @type {IterableIterator<RegExpMatchArray>} */ let itr;
        let i = 0;
        do {
          i++;
          if (i === 50) {
            throw new Error('Many loops tried, Unable to insert regex_brute_force_delimiter as hardcode_string_indicator in searching content. (The chance of this happening is nearly impossible.)');
          }
          time_now = Date.now();
          html_delimRegexBf = '<' + delimRegexBf_tagName + '>' + time_now + '</' + delimRegexBf_tagName + '>';
          itr = content_SearchOn.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(html_delimRegexBf), 'g'));
        } while (itr.next().done !== true);

        //
        const elt_delimRegexBf = document.createElement(delimRegexBf_tagName);
        elt_delimRegexBf.innerHTML = time_now;

        //
        node_inner.parentNode.insertBefore(elt_delimRegexBf, node_inner);
        const content_SearchOn_withDelim = elt_outer.innerHTML;
        //
        elt_delimRegexBf.remove();

        //
        itr = content_SearchOn_withDelim.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(html_delimRegexBf), 'gd'));
        const itrEntry_first = itr.next();
        if (itrEntry_first.done === true) {
          // no match -- node_inner is not inside elt_outer
          return -1;
        } else {
          const matcher_first = itrEntry_first.value;
          return matcher_first.indices[0][0];
        }

      }


      // @test-ex
      let elt_outer = $('<div id="main_parag">Sample<!-- comment <span>Get_My_Index</span> --> for testing <span>Get_My_Index</span>; <script>let i = 47;</script>Works?<span>A question<span>Get_My_Index</span></span></div>')[0];
      const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(elt_outer, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);
      /** @type {Node} */ let node_curr;
      while ((node_curr = treeWalker.nextNode())) {
        const nt = node_curr.nodeType;
        if (nt === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          console.log(node_curr.textContent);
        } else if (nt === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          console.log(node_curr.outerHTML);
        } else {
          console.log(node_curr.nodeValue);
        }
        console.log(get_IndHtml_of_nodeInner_in_eltOuter(node_curr, elt_outer));
      }
      console.log(elt_outer.innerHTML);

      // @test-ex
      elt_outer = $('<div id="main_parag">nothing to search</div>')[0];
      node_curr = $('<span id="non_exist">?</span>')[0];
      console.log(get_IndHtml_of_nodeInner_in_eltOuter(node_curr, elt_outer));
  ```

  - output

    ```html
    // Sample
    // 0
    //  comment <span>Get_My_Index</span> 
    // 6
    //  for testing 
    // 48
    // <span>Get_My_Index</span>
    // 61
    // Get_My_Index
    // 67
    // ; 
    // 86
    // <script>let i = 47;</script>
    // 88
    // let i = 47;
    // 96
    // Works?
    // 116
    // <span>A question<span>Get_My_Index</span></span>
    // 122
    // A question
    // 128
    // <span>Get_My_Index</span>
    // 138
    // Get_My_Index
    // 144
    // Sample<!-- comment <span>Get_My_Index</span> --> for testing <span>Get_My_Index</span>; <script>let i = 47;</script>Works?<span>A question<span>Get_My_Index</span></span>
    // -1
    ```

#### comment (not important)

- turns out.. regex is the simplest way to do it, brute forcing an unique delimiter indicator in the search content is pretty helpful...
- I was trying to find the html string representation for all the node types, & while use `Node.prevSibling / Node.parentNode` to go through all...
- (jsfiddle / code snippet somehow doesnt work with my code, but my code in Vscode is functioning fine, dont know if there is some issue with Node.js & browser...)